# SLServiceTypeTwitter’ is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0

Tags: swift

I am using `XCode 10.1` when trying to use `SLServiceTypeTwitter`, `SLServiceTypeFacebook` or any other social media ones, I get an error saying that they are `depricated since iOS 11.0`.

I downloaded an old simulator that is running an older version to see if that fixes it but each time when I run the codes it brings up the simulator with latest `iOS` version (i.e. no Twitter login option).

```
@IBAction func cameraTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func shareTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter) {
        let vc = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
        vc?.setInitialText("My food is \(navigationItem.title!)")
        vc?.add(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "hotdogBackground"))
        present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        self.navigationItem.title = "Please log in to Twitter"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score -7):

I found the solution . I load older ios versions in Xcode preferences. After I do that, I pick the iOS in the simulator (Hardware -Device) when I choose simulator Xcode show Me options to run my app on devices with specific ios’s installed.

This fix my problem.

ps: If they aren’t there (simulator), make sure you are compiling to the right target and if there isn't any you can always add simulator.